# Is there a way to do Firebase Auth Phone with USSD

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ussd

I am building a USSD app on Node JS and would like to authenticate users using the Firebase Phone auth feature. I am not sure how to achieve this if it is in fact possible.

I have a web app that does that and it uses Captcha verifier. Is it possible to have a USSD app that registers a user based on their phone number on Google Firebase's phone auth service. And how can that be achieved?

Comment: I would highly suggest contacting [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/products/other) to further help you with your concern with deep knowledge